# Windows command-line: How to copy subdirectories, not files, under a given root dir?

Tags: windows, command-line, filesystems

I have a file hierarchy like this:

```
RootDir
  /A
    /fileA.txt
  /B
    /C
       /fileC.txt
    /fileB.txt
  /otherFile1.txt
  /otherFile2.txt
```

I'd like to copy only the subdirs (i.e. `A`, `B`) and *everything under them* (meaning I want everything copied EXCEPT `otherFile1.txt` and `otherFile2.txt`).

There are a lot more than 2 dirs and 2 files under the root dir so I'd rather not specify each one by name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is powershell solution acceptable? in powershell this will be one-liner. in pure batch - might be a bit more complicated.

Comment: The title does not match the question. The answer to the question in the title is `xcopy /t`; the answer to the question in the question body is more involved.

Comment: I agree. I suppose this is one of those cases where you are actually better off doing it in xcopy than Robocopy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) and [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to accomplish this task:

```
cd SOURCE
for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir /B /AD') do @xcopy /E "%a" "DESTINATION\%a\"
```

How it works:

- Once you enter the *SOURCE* directory, the command `dir /B /AD` lists all directories (`/AD`), one by line (`/B`).
- `for /F "delims=" %a in ('...') do` goes through the output of the command `...`, sets the variable `%a` to the next line of output and executes whatever follows `do`.

  Here, `delims=` makes sure the variable holds the entire line's content. Without it, `%a` would only hold the characters up to the first space.
- `xcopy /E "%a" "DESTINATION\%a\"` copies the directory currently specified in `%a` into a folder of the same name in the directory *DESTINATION*. The `/E` switch causes the directory's contents to be copied as well.<sup>1</sup>

  Specifying the directory's name in the destination is essential. Without it, `fileA.txt` would get copied to `DESTINATION\fileA.txt` (rather than `DESTINATION\A\fileA.txt`).

  The trailing backslash is used to indicate that `%a` is the name of a directory, not a file. The double quotes are necessary to handle directory names containing spaces properly.

If this command is going to be used inside a batch file, all percent signs have to be escaped with a second percent sign, i.e., `%a` becomes `%%a`.

---

<sup>1</sup> `/E` copies empty directories as well. If this is not desired, you can use `/S` instead.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks for taking the time to write it!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the Dennis and David Ruhmann answers, but using a FOR /D loop instead of FOR /F.

```
for /d %F in (rootFolderPath\*) do @xcopy /e /i "%F" "destinationPath\%~nxF"
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could explain the difference between /F and /D flags (for the sake of completion; I know `for /?` covers that). More importantly, what does the weird-looking substitution (?) pattern at the end do?

Comment: All is explained in the help: `/F` parses text file contents, or parses a string, or parses the output of a command. `/D` iterates directories. The pattern at the end is explained at the very bottom of the help. `%~nxF` expands the value of `%F` into the name and extension, ignoring drive and path.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is using Robocopy's "/create" switch, which copies the entire folder structure only, and "0 length files only" -which I'm sure would lead to all your files being excluded

**Robocopy /e /create \(source path of folder A) \(destination path)**

**Robocopy /e /create \(source path of folder B) \(destination path)**

You could also (if they are all the same file types, or a small number of known file types) use the "Exclude File" "/xf" switch and wildcard out the file types, like this:

**Robocopy /e (source path of folder A) (destination path) /xf *.txt**

**Robocopy /e (source path of folder B) (destination path) /xf *.txt**

Comment: how will this prevent copying files under root directory?

Comment: Wouldn't this fail to copy the files under the sub-directory?

Comment: Not any more. I just added the /e ("copy subdirectories, including empty ones") switch.

Comment: I think it's not necessary to give my answer a thumbs down just because it's not the quickest solution. It does all the work- doesn't leave the OP having to manually delete the files afterwards, unlike the other answer.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to copy any files in the root of the source directory but this appears to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is easy with a Unix shell.  Here's how you might do it with my own [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm) (including the [free version](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Demo.htm).  You could do something similar with [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org) `bash` though it might a little harder.  This will copy all the subdirectories but only the subdirs of RootDir and their contents to DestinationDir.

```
cd RootDir
cp ``ld -1`` DestinationDir
```

[`ld`](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/52-PredefinedAliases.htm) is an alias for [`ls`](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/Utilities/ls.htm) that lists only directories.  The `-1` option means list the output in a single column, one entry per line.  The double backquotes mean [line-at-a-time command substitution](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/36-Quoting.htm), ensuring this will work even if some the subdir names contain spaces.

Here's a screenshot showing how it works.  Notice that it copies everything *except* the `hello.txt` file in the root.   All the subdirs *and their contents* are copied. The `ls -r` option means recursive.

[image: Copy only subdirs using Hamilton C shell]

Answer (score 1):

Native Windows CMD solution.  Copy only the subfolders (and their contents) from a RootDir.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir RootDir /a:d /b') do xcopy %%A DestDir /e /i
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by another user in the comments, the *shortest* solution which accomplishes what the OP is trying to do is simply:

**xcopy /t /e**

Comment: The OP wants to copy the contents of the subdirs as well, but `xcopy /t` only copies non-empty directories, not their contents.

Comment: Thanks Nicole- I've added the "/e" switch ("copy Empty directories and subdirectories") so it finally does what the OP wants. No room for improvement now!

Comment: This still doesn't copy any of the contents of the subdirs.  As I read the OP, I think the only files to be omitted are the files at the top. Any other files lower in the tree should be copied.

Comment: I think the OP should clarify whether he wants directores AND files (as indicated in the body) or to exclude files (as indicated in the title).

Comment: I have the broad lines of the question in the title, and the details and disambiguation in the question's body. If you can find a more  descriptive (and still succint) title, by all means, edit the title.